# WebStorm: Why is bigint type not recognized even while using TSC 3.4.x?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm building the models part of my application and for id types I wanted to switch from `number` to `bigint` AFAIK supported from TSC 3.2.x but this is what WebStorm shows ... `Unresolved type bigint`. Why is that and how to fix it?

btw ... is `bigint` JSON-convertible out of the box?

**UPDATE: Webstorm version and `tsconfig.json`**

I'm using WebStorm version 2019.1.3

and my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what IDE version do you use? Also, what target is specified in `tsconfig.json`? Per [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#caveats-1), this type is only available when targeting `esnext`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in WebStorm, please follow [WEB-39502](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39502) for updates.
As a workaround, you need to either add `esnext` to `"lib": []`:

```
 "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ]
```

or enable the TypeScript compiler service in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**.

Note that in either case you have to change the `target` to `esnext` or higher - BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ESNext.